# Nservicebus 4 with azure and RavenDB

Tags: azure, nservicebus

I see that RavenDb is the default storage for nservicebus 4 and that RavenDb has to be installed.

How does this work with nservicebus endpoints hosted as azure worker roles? I have several of these and am trying to get my mind around what I will need to do to upgrade these end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently RavenDb is not required, contrary to what the release notes currently state. I was able to configure an azure role to use subscription storage and it appears to use azure table storage with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

- Use [RavenHQ](https://ravenhq.com/) and assign the connection string, see http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859362-using-ravendb-in-nservicebus-%E2%80%93-connecting
- Use SqlServer as persistence

Comment: Thanks. So if I use raven does that mean there will be an installation requirement on the worker role?

Comment: My other worry is how does raven deal with the elasticity of azure.

Comment: Also I would guess, that for subscription storage at least, that table storage is still an option. Currently using that with the nhibernate dependency (version 3.2.8 of NSB). Is this not the case? I did not see anything about this in the release notes.

Comment: If u use RavenHQ,  no local install is required.

Comment: Yes, but that will be further cost for me. Already paying heavily on the azure front. I think I will try the table storage route for subscription storage or stay at 3.2.8 if that does not work.